Expo SDK 47 - XCode 15 build fails because of "unary_function" name mismatch
Is there any workaround for following error in Expo 47 (managed workflow) during iOS build?

❌  (ios/Pods/boost/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:131:33)

  129 | #else
  130 |         template <typename T>
> 131 |         struct hash_base : std::unary_function<T, std::size_t> {};
      |                                 ^ no template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?
  132 | #endif
  133 | 
  134 |         struct enable_hash_value { typedef std::size_t type; };

I know that the best thing to do here is upgrading Expo to version 48 or higher, but I would like to know if someone managed to make it work with version 47. I have an upgrade planned for future and I can't really do it right now :(

i think that you have to upgrade your react_native version to the to >= 0.72.5, the easiest way to do so, is to delete the node_modules folder and go to your package.json and change the version near "react-native": "0.XX.XX", to "react-native": "0.72.5" ( as minimum ) as here
